# How do I fill the transparent area inside an image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I added a white border to a PNG image with Konvajs
[image: example]

[konvajs link](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Image_Border.html)

I want to turn the transparent area inside the white border to white. So I want to paint the windows of the car white. (Red areas are transparent.)

[image: example]

Expected result:
[image: result]

Comment: You cannot target an area of a canvas or image for specific treatment unless you have the path definition. You would have to  manually define the region of the windows to have any chance of changing the colors from transparent to white or any other switch.

Comment: In case you are wondering why you got a down vote (not by me) it is because you are linking to external images rather than embedding them here. In the future, when those links break, this question will have no useful context. Also, you mention the areas of the windows but it would be better to annotate the pictures so as to avoid confusion. Basically you need to help the folks you are asking to assist you to spend as little time as possible understanding your question.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, the images are not external, they are on i.stack.imgur.com, which is the Stack Overflow account of imgur. That's okay. However, they were not embedded (as in: visible) in the question, making it hard to understand the question without opening all images in new tabs (I have fixed that). Also, the question lacks information and apparently there are requirements mentioned in comments below the answers that are not mentioned here. The question should be complete and clear. Tyoslax Beffs: you might want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could maybe do is converting you image to a SVG.

You would then have a `path` for your car windows with some class. You could afterward change the style of the SVG class in JS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, because I'm trying to convert stickers. That is, the transparent area needs to remain transparent. Only the transparent area inside the car needs to be white.

Comment: Alright, i've updated my answer with something that may suit your needs a little better.

Comment: I will need to set class for over 1 million images. I don't think this method is correct.

Comment: over a million images? Wasn't this just 1 car?? I think you should document your question more than that, because you asked a very simple question...

Comment: This was just an example. Why would I write a code for only 1 image?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem you want background color white. As your [link](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Image_Border.html) there are a function called `removeTransparency` it makes the image background color white see it.

```
      // make all pixels opaque 100% (except pixels that 100% transparent)
      function removeTransparency(canvas) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var nPixels = imageData.data.length;
        for (var i = 3; i < nPixels; i += 4) {
          if (imageData.data[i] > 0) {
            imageData.data[i] = 255;
          }
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        return canvas;
      }
```

Comment: I am already using this function and this is not the result I expected.

Comment: @TyoslaxBeffs this function do what you are need. If it doesn't work so the problem in your code. You can implement it in your question to be able to help you.